# preg replace placeholders

Tags: php

I'm trying to append a number to another number

```
$n = 123;
$str = "some string with tt=789_ and more";
echo preg_replace("/tt=[0-9]+/", "$0$n", $str);
```

I expect this to print "some string with tt=789_123 and more" for some reason i'm getting "some string with 23_ and more".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example the `$0$n` is transformed to `$0123` which can [confuse `preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) (see the section about *replacement*).

So the correct way is to do the following:

```
$n = 123;
$str = "some string with tt=789_ and more";
echo preg_replace("/tt=[0-9_]+/", "\${0}$n", $str);
```

I've also added `_` to your character class otherwise it returns `tt=789123_`.